# creating date range on csv using python-pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How to create a date range in python using **pandas** in Y-M-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['2015-07-07','2016-09-22'],['2012-02-03','2013-02-19'],['2013-02-17','2013-03-22']],columns = ['start','end'])

#change strings to date format 
df['start'] = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in df['start']]
df['end'] = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in df['end']]

df['range'] = df['end']-df['start']

df
```

Output should be:

```
    start       end         range
0   2015-07-07  2016-09-22  443 days
1   2012-02-03  2013-02-19  382 days
2   2013-02-17  2013-03-22  33 days
```

In case you want to read from csv, switch the beginning to:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
```

in case you want a concatenated column:

```
 df['details'] = [str(x)+' - '+str(y)+' has '+str(z)[:-9] for x,y,z in zip(df['start'],df['end'],df['range'])]
```

Comment: You shall be blessed but I want to list out those ranges e.g 2015-07-07 - 2016-09-22 has 443 days. I want to create something like 2015-07-07, 2015-07-08, ... until 2016-09-22

Comment: is this what you need? :                                                                  df['details'] = [str(x)+' - '+str(y)+' has '+str(z)[:-9] for x,y,z in zip(df['start'],df['end'],df['range'])]

Comment: Please I don't get to see it clearly. Maybe you can add it under the previous submission.

Comment: no problem, I'll do that

Comment: Thanks so much, very useful